# In Halo Wars what do the Forerunner life supports do?

Tags: halo-wars

I was playing Halo Wars on the skirmish map Blood Gulch or Beasley's Plateau. I found a special feature called "Forerunner life support". I sent a squad of ODST marines in it, but I didn't see anything happen. So what does the Forerunner life support do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's referred to as a [Forerunner Lifepod](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Forerunner_Lifepod) in the Halo wikia. There isn't one on Blood Gulch IIRC, only a bonus reactor and supply depot on each side. They increase your population limit by 10.